# How to trigger C/C++ Code Runner's automatic settings creation in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a C++ project running in VS Code.  The CMake file has been created.  Opening VS Code then triggers the creation of the `settings.json` file under `.vscode`.  I then create the `launch.json` file.  Things work properly.  Later, I somehow trigger the creation of another debug configuration (from the `C/C++ Runner` extension?).  My `setting.json` file goes from:

```
{
  "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/hello-world"
}
```

to:

```
{
  "cmake.sourceDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/hello-world",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcBatchPath": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "gdb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useMsvc": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warnings": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Wshadow",
    "-Wformat=2",
    "-Wconversion",
    "-Wnull-dereference",
    "-Wsign-conversion"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.enableWarnings": true,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warningsAsError": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.linkerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includeSearch": [
    "*",
    "**/*"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.excludeSearch": [
    "**/build",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.*",
    "**/.*/**",
    "**/.vscode",
    "**/.vscode/**"
  ]
}
```

My `launch.json` file also has this extra section added:

```
{
  "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  "args": [],
  "stopAtEntry": false,
  "externalConsole": false,
  "cwd": "/home/machine01/dev-workspace/repo01/hello-world",
  "program": "/home/machine01/dev-workspace/repo01/hello-world/build/Debug/outDebug",
  "MIMode": "gdb",
  "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
  "setupCommands": [
    {
      "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
      "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
      "ignoreFailures": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This automatic settings creation is very convenient.  How do I trigger this again?  I have tried many things to no avail.

Comment: why use C++ Runner, if you have a launch config and compile/cmake task just press F5

Comment: I want to use the auto-generated settings by `C++ Runner` instead of writing the JSON file myself.

Comment: the `ms-cpp` extension can create a starting launch config for you

Comment: @rioV8, are you talking about the `C/C++` extension?  The `launch.json` from that extension is not very detailed.  I still have to specify various settings for it.

Answer (score 1):

The additional settings and the "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session" configuration in launch.json are created by the C/C++ Runner extension. They will be automatically recreated for new projects opened in a fresh folder but the launcher.json configuration will fail unless the project is built using C/C++ Runner (which creates the relevant folders/files).

Documentation for building project using C/C++ Runner:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=franneck94.c-cpp-runner